# Apply Masking in Bing Map AJAX

Tags: bing-maps

I am trying to overlay an image in bing map and then mask certain parts of the image.I tried the below link and I could overlay the image. However my next step is to mask.I want the image of a particular region and not a entire rectangular image.

http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2013/05/22/image-overlays-with-bing-maps-javascript/

Any inputs on this? Does Bing Map have coordinate based masking.

Thanks!

Comment: What about multiple image that you hide dynamicaly in CSS or by using the supported methods? In clear, the image that you're adding on top is one 'img' markup and provides you with the same feature that HTML is offering. You can't just easily hide parts or an image (you might look at dynamicaly render it using Canvas, but I think it would be much harder to develop)

Comment: @NicolasBoonaert- That would be perfect if I knew what part to mask in the image. But this is kinda dynamic and based on coordinates.  I want to render the part of the image that's just above a particular city.

Comment: Then I guess you should set your clipping mask manipulation on the server side so you retrieve the appropriate image based on your geometries (city boundaries...)